# Trying to highlight Text between two words on condition of

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro I created that is almost there.The macro is intended to look for certain words and highlight them, the format of the dialog is always the same and an example is per below:

```
**=====Begin Message=====**
Message#: 10
Message Sent: 08/06/2008 04:48:09
**Susan:** I there How are you
Peter: I am great thanks
**Susan:**lekkkkkeeerrr
Peter:siiiiccckkkk
**=====End Message=====**

=====Begin Message=====
Message#: 10
Message Sent: 08/06/2008 04:48:09
Jack: Hey boyyyss…want to get shit faced
Peter: I am great thanks, keen to do it
Jack:lekkkkkeeerrr
Peter:siiiiccckkkk
=====End Message=====
```

Now what the macro will do is highlight every text that says "susan" as well as "Begin" and "end message". Then what the macro will do is open up a new word document and paste on the message that contains susan in it and the desired result should look like below:

```
**=====Begin Message=====**
Message#: 10
Message Sent: 08/06/2008 04:48:09
**Susan:** I there How are you
Peter: I am great thanks
**Susan:**lekkkkkeeerrr
Peter:siiiiccckkkk
**=====End Message=====**
```

**=====Begin Message=====**

**=====End Message=====**

Unfortunately the macro does not do that and instead it will output only everything susan said and nothing about what Peter had replied to her. as like below:

```
**=====Begin Message=====**
Message#: 10
Message Sent: 08/06/2008 04:48:09
**Susan:** I there How are you

**Susan:**lekkkkkeeerrr

**=====End Message=====**

  **=====Begin Message=====**

    **=====End Message=====**
```

the reason I highlight the Begin and end part is because the macro pastes every end and beginning that is highlighted and then takes all paragraph surrounding the Susan hihglight, but its not enough, I want everything between Begin message and end Message if the text is highlighted. Below is the code I have so far:

```
Sub CopyParagraphs()
    Dim DocA As Document
    Dim DocB As Document
    Dim para As Paragraph

    Set DocA = ActiveDocument
    Set DocB = Documents.Add

    For Each para In DocA.Paragraphs
        With para.range.Find
            .Highlight = True ' could try:  If para.range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow Then etc etc
            If .Execute() Then
                para.range.Copy
                DocB.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").range.Text = "Page " & para.range.Characters.First.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) & vbCr
                DocB.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").range.Paste
                DocB.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").range.Text = vbCr & vbCr
            End If
        End With
    Next para
End Sub
```

Please pretend in advance that all **=====Begin Message=====**,=====End Message===== and susan words are highlighted, I am just showing you the copy paragraph code I have.

Comment: [be-nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) and just flag comment that are non constructive  or rude.

Comment: Alright, I my apologies for venting, I do not take kindly towards lack of soft skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CopyMsg_JarrydWard()
    Dim DocA As Document
    Dim DocB As Document
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Set DocA = ThisDocument
    Set DocB = Documents.Add

    Dim Rg As Range, RgMsg As Range
    Dim StartWord As String, EndWord As String, NameToHighlight As String
    Dim FoundName As Boolean
    Set Rg = DocA.Content
    Rg.Find.ClearFormatting
    Rg.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    StartWord = "=====Begin Message====="
    EndWord = "=====End Message====="
    NameToHighlight = "Susan"

    With Rg.Find
        'Set the parameters for your Find method
        .Text = StartWord & "*" & EndWord
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        'Execute the Find
        .Execute
        'Loop through the results
        While .Found
            'Boolean to copy only message containing NameToHighlight
            FoundName = False
            'Keep Rg (result range for whole message) intact for later copy
            Set RgMsg = Rg.Duplicate

            'Highlight
            'Start and End
            DocA.Range(Start:=Rg.Start, End:=Rg.Start + Len(StartWord)).Bold = True
            DocA.Range(Start:=Rg.End - Len(EndWord), End:=Rg.End).Bold = True
            'NameToHighlight : here : Susan
            With RgMsg.Find
                'Set the parameters for your Find method
                .Text = NameToHighlight
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                'Execute the Find
                .Execute
                'Loop through the results
                While .Found
                    RgMsg.Bold = True
                    FoundName = True
                    'Go to the next result for NameToHighlight
                    .Execute
                Wend
            End With 'RgMsg.Find

            'Copy the whole message if NameToHighlight was found
            If FoundName Then
                Rg.Copy
                DocB.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.Text = "Page " & _
                        Rg.Characters.First.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) & vbCr
                DocB.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.Paste
                DocB.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.Text = vbCr & vbCr
            End If
            'Go to the next result for the message
            .Execute
        Wend
    End With 'Rg.Find
End Sub
```

Comment: @JarrydWard : Strange, it works for me... Did you notice that I changed `Set DocA = ActiveDocument` to `Set DocA = ThisDocument`? So if you use the code as it is, you'll need to place it in a module in the document where you text is, or you can change back `Set DocA = ActiveDocument` an use it as you used to. I'm coming back in a few to finish this! ;)

Comment: My apologies, It is my fault.,...the code actually works perfectly....thank you so much, apologies for earlier...your coding is brilliant. I just have one more question, Could it look for words that start with the word "Start" and "end" reason being is I may have extracts with "Start" and "end" and then another one with "Start1" and "end1" and both must be seen as start and end.I also want to put in multiple name, not Just Susan, would I use the "," seperator i.e "Susan,John,Peter"

Comment: @JarrydWard : NP, I had an issue to with the case, `Susan` and `susan` where recognized at the same time, I edited the code to have both! The first find use a wildcard `*`, so you can strip `StartWord` and `EndWord` to any text that will wrap the whole message and it'll get the whole range between these two words and bold  `StartWord` and `EndWord`. Btw, please take the [tour] (click, the link is embedded), to see how to accept answers! ;)

Comment: How can I find more than just one name?

Comment: I would like to add a few other names to the condition, not just susan, it can be either or...so the condition would be the "or" statement....can be susan or John or Peter

Comment: I added something like this: NameToHighlight = Array("JASON", "JAMES ") ' list of words in here

For i = 0 To UBound(NameToHighlight)

Comment: @JarrydWard : I think the easiest way would be to use Split (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) function to loop though an array, and wrap the `With RgMsg.Find`. If you are still stuck with that post a new question and you can poke me here with the link if you want! ;)

Comment: @JarrydWard : As I told earlier, **post a new question**, with your code trying to use the arrays and you can reuse the text of this one as an explanation. You can poke me here with the link then, but I'm working too mate.